# dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' mysql

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, linux-mint, dpkg

I get this error `dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'dpkg --configure -a'` when I run `sudo apt-get install` and when I run `sudo dpkg --configure -a` it keeps like this forever.

> sudo dpkg --configure -a
> Setting up mysql-server-8.0 (8.0.21-0ubuntu0.20.04.3) ...
> mysqld will log errors to /var/log/mysql/error.log
> mysqld is running as pid 6113

How do I fix this error?
I am using Linux Mint 20.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to find an answer. Here's what I did:

I deleted everything in the directory: `var/lib/dpkg/info/`
and then

> sudo apt-get clean
> sudo apt-get update
> sudo apt-get install -f

It stops the error, and I can update my OS now.